# problems passing parameters in winds in vue js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, events, two-way-binding

I have this code and I get an array in the info variable. The problem is in the delete button that calls the remove function passing the id as a parameter but it passes the first id to all elements so when I delete any element it deletes the first one instead of referring to the button

````
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{info.product_key}}</th>
      <td>{{info.name}}</td>
      <td>{{info.quantities}}</td>
      <td>{{info.quatities_sold}}</td>
      <td>{{info.cost_price}}</td>
      <td>{{info.sale_price}}</td>
      <td><button @click="showEditModal" class="btn btn-warning">editar</button></td>
       <EditProductModal 
       :_id=info._id 
       :product_key=info.product_key
       :product_name=info.name 
       :quantities=info.quantities
       :quantities_sold=info.quatities_sold
       :cost_price=info.cost_price
       :sale_price=info.sale_price
       :categories=info.categories
         />
      <td><button @click="remove(info._id)" class="btn btn-danger">excluir</button></td>
    </tr>
   
  </tbody>```
````

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, I added an answer. Hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said `I get an array in the info variable` but looks like instead of iterating you are directly using it. If you are iterating it properly using `v-for` it should pass the correct ID.

**Working Demo :**

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    info: [{
      '_id': 1, 
      'name': 'alpha'
    }, {
      '_id': 2, 
      'name': 'beta'
    }, {
      '_id': 3, 
      'name': 'gama'
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    remove(itemID) {
        console.log(itemID);
    }
  }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="item in info" :key="item._id">
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td><button @click="remove(item._id)">excluir</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```